# ranger variable importance scores from a tidymodel

Tags: tidymodels, vip

Several publications highlight that there may be biases in variable importance scores derived from machine learning models. [A recent study shows](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.07765) by Loh and Zou (2021) shows that `ranger` permutation-based variable importance scores produce unbiased results.

I am using `tidymodels` with a `ranger` engine to estimate random forest model. How can I get `ranger` variable importance scores from the resulting fit? What is the difference between the variable importance scores from `vip`? From my understanding, the vip in the example below is the random forest model-specific gini importance.

```
library(tidymodels)
library(vip)

aq <- na.omit(airquality)

model_rf <-
  rand_forest(mode = "regression") %>%
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "permutation") %>%
  fit(Ozone ~ ., data = aq)

# variable importance
vip:::vi(model_rf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to change the value of the `importance` argument to get the unbiased estimates. `ranger` has a function to get the importance scores and  the model-specific method in the `vi` package:

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(vip)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'vip'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     vi

aq <- na.omit(airquality)

set.seed(1)
model_rf <-
  rand_forest(mode = "regression") %>%
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity_corrected") %>%
  fit(Ozone ~ ., data = aq)

model_rf %>% 
  extract_fit_engine() %>% 
  ranger::importance() %>% 
  sort(decreasing = TRUE)
#>      Temp      Wind   Solar.R     Month       Day 
#> 27919.050 23028.379  6830.772  3077.430  1597.355

# the same as using ranger directly
vip:::vi(model_rf)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   Variable Importance
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 Temp         27919.
#> 2 Wind         23028.
#> 3 Solar.R       6831.
#> 4 Month         3077.
#> 5 Day           1597.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>